# Getting the Import error when trying to import EntityRecognizer from spacy.language package

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

ImportError: cannot import name 'EntityRecognizer' from 'spacy.language'.

getting the when try importing the packages in spyder,
import spacy

from spacy.gold import GoldParse

from spacy.language import EntityRecognizer

spyder version: 3.3.6

conda version: 4.8.3

Answer (score 4):

Try:
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer